# A Problem Storing Arabic Chars in Database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, unicode

I'm trying to make a registration form where people will take the link and enter their information, which then gets gets stored in the database. Unfortunately, when I try to enter information in Arabic using the form ,it gets stored in PhpMyAdmin as an unknown chars.
I have tried the following without success.

- Set the default charset in the index as follows:

  ```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  ```
- Set the default charset in the database handler page:

  ```
  $cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf_8';
  $cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
  ```
- Changed the database Collation to `utf8_general_ci`
- Changed the table Collation to `utf8_general_ci`
- Exported as sql and edit the charset but I found it UTF-8 already.
- Made sure that my browser unicode is set to UTF-8.

And that's an example on how it works:

```
<form action="signup.php" method="POST" class="form">
<input type="text" name="first"><br />
<input type="text" name="uid"><br />
<input type="date" name="dob"><br />
```

-

```
$first = $_POST['first'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO students (first, uid, dob)
 VALUES ('$first','$uid', '$dob')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

And they're connected through a required file to connect to the db.

```
$cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf_8';
$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test2");

if (!$conn ) {
    die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());

}
```

No idea what's causing this and I need a fast fix.

[image: Preview of the error]

Comment: PhpMyAdmin does not store anything.  However, even your browser settings might be wrong.  You didn't tell how the input gets into the database, so there can be one to a hundred steps where it goes wrong.

Comment: Edited the question to make it more clear. @dezso

Comment: Try running this query right after the connection: `SET NAMES utf8`

Comment: Use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` in your MySQL. You should also employ `mbstring_` in PHP as outlined in the link posted here: [This topic will solve your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem.

```
if (!mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($conn));
}
```